# regex - character class subtraction

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I want to match whitespaces and any kind of punctuation character except `.`.

I'm trying this:
`([^\pP-[\.]\pZ])`

But isn't working. I need to use a capturing group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Character class substraction isn't a PCRE feature (the PHP regex flavor).

You can write this instead: `([^\PP.]|\s)` *(add the `u` modifier to extend the `\s` character class to all the unicode white-spaces and to read the string as UTF8)*

The idea is to use a kind of double negation to exclude the dot. `\PP` is all that is not a punctuation character. `[^\PP]` matches all punctuation characters (like `\pP`) but this time you can use the character class negation `[^...]` to exclude what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you whitespace and all symbols/punctuation.

```
[^.\w]
```

http://regexr.com/3bddt

The ^ is used to exclude the characters that follow it. So [^.\w] says exclude . and all word characters, leaving only symbols and punctuation